# can avaliable_primary_key() re-utilize deleted smaller primary_keys?

Tags: multi-index, keys, primarykey

"table_name.available_primary_key()," is 'auto incrementing'. Is available_primary_key able to re-use previously deleted primary keys and re-utilize them?

eg. assuming some random primary_keys such as 2, 9, 31, 56, 66, & 89, etc.. have been erased from a table filled with the max possible primary_keys, would it begin utilizing the next 'smallest' available_primary_key?

I want to  assume the answer is yes, but the manual seems to imply otherwise?

https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/v1.8/group__multiindex/?query=available_primary_key()&page=1#function-available_primary_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `available_primary_key()` returns `(the primary key of the last item) + 1`.